# Please Verify My ASP.NET Code to insert data to oracle database

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, insert

No matter what I do the following code does not seem to work. It always breaks at `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Anything I am missiong?

Always throws

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        int room_id = Int32.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
        int activity_id = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        string session_code = TextBox1.Text;
        int start_time = GetTimeSeconds(startTime.Text);
        int period = GetTimeSeconds(duration.Text);
        string book_date = bookDate.Text;
        string ref_no = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;

        conn.Open();

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
            "insert into BRAZESH.ALL_SESSION(SESSION_CODE,START_TIME,\"PERIOD\",BOOKED_DATE,ROOM_ID,ACTIVITY_ID,REF_NO)" +
            " values ('" + session_code + "'," + start_time + "," + period + ",to_date('" + book_date + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd')," + room_id + "," + activity_id + ", '" + ref_no + "')"))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are never assigning the OracleConnection `conn` to your OracleCommand `cmd`.

Comment: You should be using parametrized queries and bind variables. The code you are using has SQL injection vunerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using **conn** while defining the connection to be used by the command. use the following line. Read details on usage [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65t0yd1x(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
        "insert into BRAZESH.ALL_SESSION(SESSION_CODE,START_TIME,\"PERIOD\",BOOKED_DATE,ROOM_ID,ACTIVITY_ID,REF_NO)" +
        " values ('" + session_code + "'," + start_time + "," + period + ",to_date('" + book_date + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd')," + room_id + "," + activity_id + ", '" + ref_no + "')",conn))
```